# Creating a global variable from a function's return value

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at Addy Osmani's gist for a publication/subscription pattern here:

https://github.com/addyosmani/pubsubz/blob/master/pubsubz.js

He surfaces his object as a global like this:

```
;(function ( window, doc, undef ) {

var topics = {},
    subUid = -1,
    pubsubz ={};

....

getPubSubz = function(){
    return pubsubz;
};

window.pubsubz = getPubSubz();
```

What is the value of creating that `getPubSubz` function? Wouldn't it be more straightforward to simply write:

```
window.pubsubz = pubsubz;
```

Comment: He also uses undef although its not needed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in this case, because `getPubSubz` is only called in one place, immediately after declaring it, it could safely be inlined.

It's hard to say exactly what the author had in mind, but in a growing code base there may be some value to having a "getter" function which could be modified if the act of getting the `pubsubz` object required more advanced logic.

Comment: Could you give a concrete exmaple of how it will be useful? In other languages getters and setters are used for encapsulation but in this case I don't see the advantage.

Comment: @Hazaart: If the code grows to access the `pubsubz` object from many different places, and then one day you realize that you want to use a different `pubSubz` instance depending on the state of a toggle variable, it would be nice to only need to change the implementation of the `getPubSubz` method, rather than everything that's accessing it. Of course, in that case, it would be unwise to expose the object  as a global variable. As I said, it's hard to know what the author had in mind there.

Answer (score 2):

It absolutely would be.

There are only two potential reasons why a getter would be used in this case:

1. There was previously some additional code inside the getter (logging, perhaps)
2. Addy Osmani's just following good practice*, and including a getter—even adding the opportunity to add additonal code in the future.

Through the power of GitHub, we can actually [eliminate option one](https://github.com/addyosmani/pubsubz/commit/c6f533c294982bc82f1f187d6d5d9b4848c459df), as the getter was added in its current state—so I think we can conclusively say that it's just a matter of good practice here.

<sup>*as jantimon alludes to in the comments below, this isn't particularly advantageous in most cases (including this one) and this code does not necessarily need to followed as an example.</sup>

Comment: @jantimon fine, it's not particularly advantageous for JS, you got me.
Maybe just old habits from languages where it is good practice :)